# The expandablelistview adapter child not updated on runtime by calling notifyDataSetChange

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, notifydatasetchanged

There is a button on BaseExpandableListAdapter on group view for adding comments in its child. When adding the item to the list and called notifyDataSetChanged() inside that adapter class, it is not changing instantly but changed after collapsing and expanding the list.

```
  private List<String> ParentItem;

  private LinkedHashMap<String, List<JsonCase>> ChildItem;

  public View getChildView(final int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final JsonCase expandedListText = (JsonCase) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.hearing_detail,parent, false);

    }

        final EditText comment = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        TextView commentorName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentorName);
        TextView commentDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentDate);
        comment.setText("" + expandedListText.details);
        if(expandedListText.commentorName!=null &&expandedListText.commentorName.equals("")){
            commentorName.setEnabled(false);
        }else{
            commentorName.setText(expandedListText.commentorName);
        }

        commentDate.setText(expandedListText.date);

    return convertView;
}

public void addCaseHearingsToAdapter(int listPosition){

    String hearingId = this.ChildItem.get(this.ParentItem.get(listPosition)).get(0).hearingId;
    String userId = PreferenceData.getLoggedInUserId(context);
    JsonCase comment = new JsonCase();
    comment.commentId = "";
    comment.hearingId = hearingId;
    comment.commentedBy = userId;
    comment.details = "";
    comment.commentorName = "";
    comment.date =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    this.ChildItem.get(this.ParentItem.get(listPosition)).add(comment);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

After clicking add comment button child not updated:
[image: After clicking add comment button child not updated]

After collapsing and expanding again child updated:
[image: After collapsing and expanding again child updated]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in my case, the height of expandableListView is not updated so it causes a problem on runtime. After digging into code. I call this setListViewHeight function after notifyDataSetChanged(), makes my expendable list view updated on runtime. I set the Height of my expandablelistView as:

```
   public static void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView, int group) {
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
            View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
        View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
        groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group)) || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
            for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                        listView);
                listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight()+1;

            }
        }
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    int height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
    if (height < 10)
        height = 200;
    params.height = height;
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to refresh adapter like

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: is its place in addCaseHearingsToAdapter function  ?

Comment: addCaseHearingsToAdapter()  function is in expandableAdapterClass so this getActivity() function is not resolved in this expandable adapter class

Comment: i am doing like this         new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }); but it is not working again

Comment: i also check this link but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374378/force-expandablelistview-to-update-data-when-notifydatasetchanged-is-called  but find nothing