# nested listView has not full size in cardView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, cardview

i need help.
i have a RecyclerView containing different View such as Cardviews. Those CardViews contains a ListView

the cardViews height is wrap content and the listviews hight is also wrap content.

the listView in the first card contains three items
the second card only one and the last card has a subitem.

how can i archive that the cards grow if their content change or if the expandableListView opens

i'm sorry for my bad engish

[Screenshot of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaLqN.jpg)
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_vocdetail_general"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/card_vocdetail_expandableList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_vocdetail_more"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_vocdetail_expandableList">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/card_vocdetail_more_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/card_detail_voc_more_sides"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_vocdetail_expandableList" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView28"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/show_more" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: As an option you can check this post for ListView: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295080/android-wrap-content-is-not-working-with-listview

Comment: Try calculate the height of ExpandableListView on runtime. Do something similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945605/the-expandablelistview-adapter-child-not-updated-on-runtime-by-calling-notifydat Hope that helps!